# Some Problems of Indy 10 IdHTTP Implementation

Tags: c++, c++builder, indy, indy10, idhttp

In regard to Indy 10 of IdHTTP, many things have been running perfectly, but there are a few things that don't work so well here. That is why, once again, I need your help.

Download button has been running perfectly. I'm using the following code :

```
void __fastcall TForm1::DownloadClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  MyFile = SaveDialog->FileName;
  TFileStream* Fist = new TFileStream(MyFile, fmCreate | fmShareDenyNone);
  Download->Enabled = false;
  Urlz = Edit1->Text;
  Url->Caption = Urlz;
   try
    {
     IdHTTP->Get(Edit1->Text, Fist);
     IdHTTP->Connected();
     IdHTTP->Response->ResponseCode = 200;
     IdHTTP->ReadTimeout = 70000;
     IdHTTP->ConnectTimeout = 70000;
     IdHTTP->ReuseSocket;
     Fist->Position = 0;
    }
   __finally
  {
    delete Fist;
    Form1->Updated();
  }
}
```

However, a `"Cancel Resume"` button is still can't resume interrupted downloads. Meant, it is always sending back the entire file every time I call `Get()` though I've used `IdHTTP->Request->Ranges` property.

I use the following code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::CancelResumeClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  MyFile = SaveDialog->FileName;;
  TFileStream* TFist = new TFileStream(MyFile, fmCreate | fmShareDenyNone);

 if (IdHTTP->Connected() == true)
   {
    IdHTTP->Disconnect();
    CancelResume->Caption = "RESUME";
    IdHTTP->Response->AcceptRanges = "Bytes";
   }
 else
   {
  try {
   CancelResume->Caption = "CANCEL";
   // IdHTTP->Request->Ranges == "0-100";
   // IdHTTP->Request->Range = Format("bytes=%d-",ARRAYOFCONST((TFist->Position)));
   IdHTTP->Request->Ranges->Add()->StartPos = TFist->Position;
   IdHTTP->Get(Edit1->Text, TFist);
   IdHTTP->Request->Referer = Edit1->Text;
   IdHTTP->ConnectTimeout = 70000;
   IdHTTP->ReadTimeout = 70000;
    }
  __finally {
    delete TFist;
   }
}
```

Meanwhile, by using the FormatBytes function, [found here](http://bcbj.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=2677&p=8229&sid=052d4381da7a21c314bd66208a2150fc#p8229), has been able to shows only the size of download files. But still unable to determine the speed of download or transfer speed.

I'm using the following code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::IdHTTPWork(TObject *ASender, TWorkMode AWorkMode, __int64 AWorkCount)
  {
   __int64 Romeo = 0;
   Romeo = IdHTTP->Response->ContentStream->Position;
   // Romeo = AWorkCount;
   Download->Caption = FormatBytes(Romeo) + " (" + IntToStr(Romeo) + " Bytes)";
   ForSpeed->Caption = FormatBytes(Romeo);
   ProgressBar->Position = AWorkCount;
   ProgressBar->Update();
   Form1->Updated();
 }
```

Please advise and give an example. Any help would sure be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DownloadClick()` method:

1. Calling `Connected()` is useless, since you don't do anything with the result. Nor is there any guarantee that the connection will remain connected, as the server could send a `Connection: close` response header. I don't see anything in your code that is asking for HTTP keep-alives.  Let `TIdHTTP` manage the connection for you.
2. You are forcing the `Response->ResponseCode` to 200.  Don't do that.  Respect the response code that the server actually sent.  The fact that no exception was raised means the response was successful whether it is 200 or 206.
3. You are reading the `ReuseSocket` property value and ignoring it.
4. There is no need to reset the `Fist->Position` property to 0 before closing the file.

Now, with that said, your `CancelResumeClick()` method has many issues.

1. You are using the `fmCreate` flag when opening the file.  If the file already exists, you will overwrite it from scratch, thus `TFist->Position` will ALWAYS be 0.  Use `fmOpenReadWrite` instead so an existing file will open as-is.  And then you have to seek to the end of the file to provide the correct `Position` to the `Ranges` header.
2. You are relying on the socket's `Connected()` state to make decisions.  DO NOT do that.  The connection may be gone after the previous response, or may have timed out and been closed before the new request is made.  The file can still be resumed either way.  HTTP is stateless.  It does not matter if the socket remains open between requests, or is closed in between.  Every request is self-contained.  Use information provided in the previous response to govern the next request.  Not the socket state.
3. You are modifying the value of the `Response->AcceptRanges` property, instead of using the value provided by the previous response.  The server tells you if the file supports resuming, so you have to remember that value, or query it before then attempting to resumed download.
4. When you actually call `Get()`, the server may or may not respect the requested `Range`, depending on whether the requested file supports byte ranges or not.  If the server responds with a response code of 206, the requested range is accepted, and the server sends ONLY the requested bytes, so you need to APPEND them to your existing file.  However, if the server response with a response code of 200, the server is sending the entire file from scratch, so you need to REPLACE your existing file with the new bytes.  You are not taking that into account.

In your `IdHTTPWork()` method, in order to calculate the download/transfer speed, you have to keep track of how many bytes are actually being transferred in between each event firing.  When the event is fired, save the current `AWorkCount` and tick count, and then the next time the event is fired, you can compare the new `AWorkCount` and current ticks to know how much time has elapsed and how many bytes were transferred.  From those value, you can calculate the speed, and even the estimated time remaining.

As for your progress bar, you can't use `AWorkCount` alone to calculate a new position.  That only works if you set the progress bar's `Max` to `AWorkCountMax` in the `OnWorkBegin` event, and that value is not always know before a download begins.  You need to take into account the size of the file being downloaded, whether it is being downloaded fresh or being resumed, how many bytes are being requested during a resume, etc.  So there is lot more work involved in displaying a progress bar for a HTTP download.

Now, to answer your two questions:

> How to retrieve and save the download file to a disk by using its original name?

It is provided by the server in the `filename` parameter of the `Content-Disposition` header, and/or in the `name` parameter of the `Content-Type` header.  If neither value is provided by the server, you can use the filename that is in the URL you are requesting. `TIdHTTP` has a `URL` property that provides the parsed version of the last requested URL.

However, since you are creating the file locally before sending your download request, you will have to create a local file using a temp filename, and then rename the local file after the download is complete.  Otherwise, use `TIdHTTP.Head()` to determine the real filename (you can also use it to determine if resuming is supported) before creating the local file with that filename, then use `TIdHTTP.Get()` to download to that local file.  Otherwise, download the file to memory using `TMemoryStream` instead of `TFileStream`, and then save with the desired filename when complete.

> when I click http://get.videolan.org/vlc/2.2.1/win32/vlc-2.2.1-win32.exe then the server will process requests to its actual url. http://mirror.vodien.com/videolan/vlc/2.2.1/win32/vlc-2.2.1-win32.exe. The problem is that IdHTTP will not automatically grab through it.

That is because VideoLan is not using an HTTP redirect to send clients to the real URL (`TIdHTTP` supports HTTP redirects).  VideoLan is using an HTML redirect instead (`TIdHTTP` does not support HTML redirects).  When a webbrowser downloads the first URL, a 5 second countdown timer is displayed before the real download then begins.  As such, you will have to manually detect that the server is sending you an HTML page instead of the real file (look at the `TIdHTTP.Response.ContentType` property for that), parse the HTML to determine the real URL, and then download it.  This also means that you cannot download the first URL directly into your target local file, otherwise you will corrupt it, especially during a resume.  You have to cache the server's response first, either to a temp file or to memory, so you can analyze it before deciding how to act on it.  It also means you have to remember the real URL for resuming, you cannot resume the download using the original countdown URL.

Try something more like the following instead.  It does not take into account for everything mentioned above (particularly speed/progress tracking, HTML redirects, etc), but should get you a little closer:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::DownloadClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    Urlz = Edit1->Text;
    Url->Caption = Urlz;

    IdHTTP->Head(Urlz);
    String FileName = IdHTTP->Response->RawHeaders->Params["Content-Disposition"]["filename"];
    if (FileName.IsEmpty())
    {
        FileName = IdHTTP->Response->RawHeaders->Params["Content-Type"]["name"];
        if (FileName.IsEmpty())
            FileName = IdHTTP->URL->Document;
    }

    SaveDialog->FileName = FileName;
    if (!SaveDialog->Execute()) return;

    MyFile = SaveDialog->FileName;
    TFileStream* Fist = new TFileStream(MyFile, fmCreate | fmShareDenyWrite);
    try
    {
        try
        {
            Download->Enabled = false;
            Resume->Enabled = false;

            IdHTTP->Request->Clear();
            //...

            IdHTTP->ReadTimeout = 70000;
            IdHTTP->ConnectTimeout = 70000;

            IdHTTP->Get(Urlz, Fist);
        }
        __finally
        {
            delete Fist;
            Download->Enabled = true;
            Updated();
        }
    }
    catch (const EIdHTTPProtocolException &)
    {
        DeleteFile(MyFile);
        throw;
    }
}

void __fastcall TForm1::ResumeClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    TFileStream* Fist = new TFileStream(MyFile, fmOpenReadWrite | fmShareDenyWrite);
    try
    {
        Download->Enabled = false;
        Resume->Enabled = false;

        IdHTTP->Request->Clear();
        //...

        Fist->Seek(0, soEnd);
        IdHTTP->Request->Ranges->Add()->StartPos = Fist->Position;
        IdHTTP->Request->Referer = Edit1->Text;

        IdHTTP->ConnectTimeout = 70000;
        IdHTTP->ReadTimeout = 70000;

        IdHTTP->Get(Urlz, Fist);
    }
    __finally
    {
        delete Fist;
        Download->Enabled = true;
        Updated();
    }
}

void __fastcall TForm1::IdHTTPHeadersAvailable(TObject*Sender, TIdHeaderList *AHeaders, bool &VContinue)
{
    Resume->Enabled = ( ((IdHTTP->Response->ResponseCode == 200) || (IdHTTP->Response->ResponseCode == 206)) && TextIsSame(AHeaders->Values["Accept-Ranges"], "bytes") );

    if ((IdHTTP->Response->ContentStream) && (IdHTTP->Request->Ranges->Count > 0) && (IdHTTP->Response->ResponseCode == 200))
        IdHTTP->Response->ContentStream->Size = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I still get some error message here. But I have sent a post on atozed forum to clear my problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Romeo:

Also, you can try a following function to determine the real download filename.

I've translated this to C++ based on the [RRUZ'function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10988325). So far so good, I'm using it on my simple IdHTTP download program, too.

But, this translation result is of course still need value improvement input from Remy Lebeau, RRUZ, or any other master here.

```
String __fastcall GetRemoteFileName(const String URI)
{
    String result;
    try
    {
        TIdHTTP* HTTP = new TIdHTTP(NULL);
        try
        {
            HTTP->Head(URI);
            result = HTTP->Response->RawHeaders->Params["Content-Disposition"]["filename"];
            if (result.IsEmpty())
            {
                result = HTTP->Response->RawHeaders->Params["Content-Type"]["name"];
                if (result.IsEmpty())
                    result = HTTP->URL->Document;
            }
        }
        __finally
        {
            delete HTTP;
        }
    }
    catch(const Exception &ex)
    {
        ShowMessage(const_cast<Exception&>(ex).ToString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This code leaks the `TIdURI` object, and leaks the `TIdHTTP` object if `Head()` fails for any reason, and if the response succeeds and does provide a filename. Also, do not use `Free()` in C++, use `delete` instead. I would also suggest not creating the `TIdURI` object unless the response does not provide a filename, since that is the only time the `TIdURI` object is actually being used.

Comment: In fact, you don't need the `TIdURI` object at all, because you can use the one built-in to `TIdHTTP` instead: `result = HTTP->URL->Document;`

Comment: I've edited it. Thank you Remy for your improvement input.

Comment: @Munfaqqiha: Your edit only addressed one of the several bugs I pointed out.  I have corrected the others.